# Regarding table access

Tags: oracle, security

How to revoke access for particular table from an user who have 'select any table' privilege?

I want to block access to system tables that have password details such as user$ etc..

DB : Oracle 11.2.0.4

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible. You're going to have to sort out your security PROPERLY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the [O7_DICTIONARY_ACCESSIBILITY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams159.htm#REFRN10133) parameter is set to false, users with SELECT ANY TABLE privilege can not access tables such as SYS.USER$, unless they have direct privileges to them.